# MLFlow - How to migrate or copy a run from one experiment to other?

Tags: mlflow

I am trying to move a run in MLflow from one experiment to another. Does anybody know if its possible? If yes, how? (I use Python API)

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow-export-import

You can copy a run from one experiment to another - either in the same tracking server or between two tracking servers. Caveats apply if they are Databricks MLflow tracking servers.

Comment: The package supports a 3-month old MLflow Server (or newer)... to new for many prod environments... But fixing the link (it was moved to "mlflow" namespace).

Answer (score 3):

For local users, I directly move run folders and modify the experiment *id* in meta.yaml.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> For local users, I directly move run folders and modify the experiment
> id in meta.yaml.

To help elaborate, every run has its own folder, which basically contains more folders like "artifacts", "metrics", "params", and "tags", you could find a "meta.yaml" file in that directory.

[folder example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfINj.png)

Open the meta.yaml file and you should find the `experiment_id`, simply change the number behind it should do the trick.

[meta.yaml example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm6GE.png)